# How to append string into list using list comprehension

Tags: python, python-3.x, list-comprehension

Ex:

```
a = []
a.append('Hello')
```

Which will give the output: `['Hello']`

Could you please tell me How to do the same using list comprehension?

Comment: `['Hello' for _ in range(1)]`

Comment: What is your intention? Why do you want to use list comprehension?

Answer (score 1):

If you only have

```
a = []
a.append('Hello')
```

as you know, it would be most practical to simply do

```
a = ['Hello']
```

But if you want to append multiple `'Hello'`s to the list, you can do it like

```
a = ['Hello' for _ in range(amount)]
```

Where the `amount` variable should be replaced with the number of `'Hello'`s you want in the list.

Another way to do the above is

```
a = ['Hello'] * amount
```

Answer (score 1):

You actually do not need to use list comprehension here. Just simply do:

```
a=['Hello']
```

You can do it by doing

```
a = ['Hello' for i in range(1)]
```

But it will just lead to more memory allocation than needed.